# Understanding of the limit of $\frac {1} {x}\to0$ as $x\to\infty$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $\varepsilon >0$. Choose $M=1/\varepsilon$.

If $x>M$ then $\left| \dfrac {1} {x}-0\right| =\left| \dfrac {1} {x}\right| =\dfrac {1} {\left| x\right| }=\dfrac {1} {x} <1/M=\varepsilon$.

**My question is:** How did $\dfrac {1} {\left| x\right| }=\dfrac {1} {x}$ be? I.e., is $x$ positive, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x > M = \frac{1}{\epsilon} > 0$$

Comment: Yes. Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

The convention is that $x \to \infty$ means $x \to +\infty$.

We're only interested at the behavior of the limitand for $x$ being a sufficiently large positive number. Negative numbers are "in the other direction".